# Laptop doesn't boot after authorizing a new key in secure boot

Tags: boot, bios, asus-laptop, black-screen-of-death, secure-boot

I have an ASUS ROG Strix laptop with double boot (Windows 10 and Ubuntu 19.10) on it. After updating Ubuntu, secure boot started complaining about unauthorized software, so I tried to manually authorize Ubuntu through secure boot's "authorize a new key" option in BIOS (I know, it was a stupid idea). After adding a new key and restarting the laptop, it was unable to boot into the system (it powers up, but it's just a black screen, no logo or anything). I brought it to a repair center and they said that the problem is with bios chip. After ordering a new bios chip and switching it with an old one, nothing changed (could it be that the new chip is broken as well?). Then, they said that the problem might be with a battery. Obviously, after changing the battery, nothing happened as well. Had anyone encountered the same problem before? Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tired resetting the BIOS/UEFI settings to factory default?

Comment: @EugenRieck The problem is that I couldn't access BIOS altogether. I tried every possible key combination, but it's just a black screen.